# Не загружается картинка через AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Появилась проблема - не загружается изображение на сервер. Я думаю, дело в AJAX, но так и не понял, что именно.
Заранее спасибо.

**HTML**

```
<form id="imgur">
    <input type="file" class="imgur" name="image">
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('input[type=file]').on("change", function() {
    var $files = $(this).get(0).files;
    var formData = new FormData;
    formData.append("image", $files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: {
            test: formData
        },
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.IMGUR_TOKEN));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])),
        'album' => IMGUR_IMAGE_ALBUM,
        'title' => 'title'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $reply = json_decode($response);
    $image = $reply->data->id;

    echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
```

Comment: А url: '' в js чо пустое? как бы для примера? у самого все заполнено? в реальном проекте?

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов пустое, потому что php-скрипт находится в том же файле, что и js. Другме скрипты с пустым url работают отлично, а вот передать картинку в php через ajax ни как не получается